# fill blank with elements of array

Tags: javascript

I want to fill the '_' with reference array :

```js
const reference = ['this is', 'a beautiful', 'car'];
const blank = ['I know', '_'];


console.log(fillBlank(reference))

function fillBlank(reference) {

    const ref = reference.join(' ');

    if(blank.length) {
    return // I know this is a beautiful car
  } else {
    return ref;
  }
  
}
```

Note that we may have blank in different places but we only have one in each blank array:

```
const blank = ['I know', '_'];
const blank = ['_', 'I know'];
const blank = ['I know', '_', 'right?'];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can map and join

```js
const reference = ['this is', 'a beautiful', 'car'];
const ref = reference.join(' ');

const fillBlank = (blank,ref) => blank.map(item => item === "_" ? ref : item).join(", ")


console.log(fillBlank(['I know', '_'],ref))
console.log(fillBlank(['_', 'I know'],ref))
console.log(fillBlank(['I know', '_', 'right?'],ref))
```

We can take this a little step further and uppercase the first letter of the ref if needed

```js
const reference = ['this is', 'a beautiful', 'car'];
const ref = reference.join(' ');

const fillBlank = (blank,ref) => blank.map((item,i) => item === "_" ? i>0? ref : ref.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + ref.slice(1) : item).join(", ")


console.log(fillBlank(['I know', '_'],ref))
console.log(fillBlank(['_', 'I know'],ref))
console.log(fillBlank(['I know', '_', 'right?'],ref))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of the 'return // I know this is a beautiful car':

```
return blank.map(item => item === '_' ? ref : item).join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fillBlank(arrToReplace, reference) {
    const concatedRef = reference.join(' ');
    arrToReplace.splice(arrToReplace.findIndex(el => el === '_'), 1, concatedRef);
    return arrToReplace.join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function fillBlank(blank, reference) {
  return blank.join(' ').replace('_', reference.join(' '));
}

const filled_blank = fillBlank(
  ['I know', '_'],
  ['this is', 'a beautiful', 'car']
);

console.log(filled_blank);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Essentially you're going to find the position of the blank and replace it with the contents of the Reference array.

```js
const reference = ['this is', 'a beautiful', 'car'];
const blank = ['I know', '_'];


console.log(fillBlank(reference))

function fillBlank(reference) {

    if(blank.length) {
      const res = [...blank];
      //Find the blank first
      const idx = res.findIndex(item => item === '_');
      //Replace the '_' with the array items 
      res.splice(idx, 1, ...reference)
      const final = res.join (' ');
      return final; // I know this is a beautiful car
    } else {
      return ref;
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill an index in an array with another array, you can use splice function in javascript.

```
const reference = ['this is', 'a beautiful', 'car'];
const blank = ['I know', '_', 'Right?'];

console.log(fillBlank(reference));
                
function fillBlank(reference) {
    const isBlank = (element) => element == '_';
    const blankIndex = blank.findIndex(isBlank);
                    
    if (blankIndex > 0) {
        blank.splice(blankIndex, 1, ...reference);
        return blank
    }
    return ref;
}
```

splice function works like this: You give it a start index, number of elements to remove and what to put there.

The '...' is an expansion operator which will expand the elements of reference so instead of an array, it gives you each item individually